# How to calculate the standard deviation of a list of m x n matrices in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

Say I have a data set of 100 data. The interesting part about this data set is that each data is a 4x3 matrix. My question is how should I calculate the standard deviation of this data set? I tried the following code, but I don't know if the result is correct. If it is correct, I want to know how it works. I know the standard deviation equation for 1d data, but I don't know the definition of std for a collection of m x n data. There is only explanation for 1d data in the docstring of np.std.

```
import numpy as np
datalist = []
for _ in range(100):
    data = np.random.random((4,3))
    datalist.append(data)
std = np.std(np.asarray(datalist))
print(std)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're having unnecessary steps. To begin with, you can get 100 matrices of 4x3 like this:

```
x = np.random.rand(100, 4, 3)
```

Then just call `np.std` on it:

```
np.std(x)
```

```
0.2827262559096299
```

That's if you want the standard deviation of all values. If you want it *per matrix cell*, specify the `axis` argument:

```
np.std(x, axis=0)
```

```
array([[0.27863211, 0.2670126 , 0.28752064],
       [0.28540484, 0.25365294, 0.28905531],
       [0.28848584, 0.27695767, 0.26886147],
       [0.27138472, 0.3135065 , 0.29361115]])
```

`axis=0` means that it's going to collapse the axis 0 (the one with size 100), which will return a matrix of 4x3.

Comment: I want to know is np.std(x) dividing by 100, 99 or 98?

Comment: it's computed using `len(x)` so 100 when `axis=0`, otherwise it's the length of the flattened array, so 100*4*3 (which will return a single number)